# Sonos integration: Missing user content (when other content is there)

Tags: integration, sonos

I have the next problem with backend integration with Sonos.

Root collection contains a few collections like Featured playlists, Featured releases, My playlists, Favourite tracks, Favourite releases.

First two collections have the data and it's visible on Sonos controller.
But other "user" collections are empty on Sonos.

The responses from API are identical, there is a data in both. See request/response below (from self-testing tool).

MediaCollection definitions:

```
<ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>FEATURED_PLAYLISTS</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>collection</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:title>Featured Playlists</ns1:title>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
<ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>FAVOURITE_PLAYLISTS</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>collection</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:title>Favourite Playlists</ns1:title>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
```

Request 1 (WORKS): getMetadata(FEATURED_PLAYLISTS, 0, 100, None)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <tns:credentials>
         <tns:deviceId>00-00-00-00-00-00:Z</tns:deviceId>
         <tns:deviceProvider>Sonos</tns:deviceProvider>
         <tns:sessionId>21743ab4b6413a5e5b4a7e50b7cf57bd45a2e969</tns:sessionId>
      </tns:credentials>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:getMetadata>
         <ns1:id>FEATURED_PLAYLISTS</ns1:id>
         <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
         <ns1:count>100</ns1:count>
      </ns1:getMetadata>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response 1:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
         <ns1:getMetadataResult>
            <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
            <ns1:count>91</ns1:count>
            <ns1:total>91</ns1:total>
            <ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:65002</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:title>Klassiske album</ns1:title>
               <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
               <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
               <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
               <ns1:albumArtURI>http://example.com/1_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
            <ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:132</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:title>Nytt og norsk</ns1:title>
               <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
               <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
               <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
               <ns1:albumArtURI>http://example.com/2_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
            </ns1:mediaCollection> ...
```

Request 2 (NOT WORKING): getMetadata(FAVOURITE_PLAYLISTS, 0, 100, None)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <tns:credentials>
         <tns:deviceId>00-00-00-00-00-00:Z</tns:deviceId>
         <tns:deviceProvider>Sonos</tns:deviceProvider>
         <tns:sessionId>21743ab4b6413a5e5b4a7e50b7cf57bd45a2e969</tns:sessionId>
      </tns:credentials>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:getMetadata>
         <ns1:id>FAVOURITE_PLAYLISTS</ns1:id>
         <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
         <ns1:count>100</ns1:count>
      </ns1:getMetadata>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response 2:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
         <ns1:getMetadataResult>
            <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
            <ns1:count>5</ns1:count>
            <ns1:total>5</ns1:total>
            <ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:75151</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:title>Rockfestival 2015</ns1:title>
               <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
               <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
               <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
               <ns1:albumArtURI>http://example.com/3_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
            <ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:40732</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:title>New tracks</ns1:title>
               <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
               <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
               <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
               <ns1:albumArtURI>http://example.com/4_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
            </ns1:mediaCollection> ...
```

Question: Why user data is missing on Sonos?

**EDIT 1:**

Compete getMetadata response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
        <ns1:getMetadataResult>
           <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
           <ns1:count>5</ns1:count>
           <ns1:total>5</ns1:total>
           <ns1:mediaCollection>
              <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:75151</ns1:id>
              <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
              <ns1:title>Malakoff Rockfestival 2015</ns1:title>
              <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
              <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
              <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
              <ns1:albumArtURI>http://static.beat.no/covers/7d/static/img/sleeveart/00/033/740/0003374041_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
           </ns1:mediaCollection>
           <ns1:mediaCollection>
              <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:40732</ns1:id>
              <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
              <ns1:title>Anbefalte nye låter</ns1:title>
              <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
              <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
              <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
              <ns1:albumArtURI>http://static.beat.no/covers/7d/static/img/sleeveart/00/047/247/0004724773_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
           </ns1:mediaCollection>
           <ns1:mediaCollection>
              <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:9318</ns1:id>
              <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
              <ns1:title>Beat Topp 20</ns1:title>
              <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
              <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
              <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
              <ns1:albumArtURI>http://static.beat.no/covers/7d/static/img/sleeveart/00/046/345/0004634531_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
           </ns1:mediaCollection>
           <ns1:mediaCollection>
              <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:15803</ns1:id>
              <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
              <ns1:title>Cupfinale!</ns1:title>
              <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
              <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
              <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
              <ns1:albumArtURI>http://static.beat.no/covers/7d/static/img/sleeveart/00/001/351/0000135178_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
           </ns1:mediaCollection>
           <ns1:mediaCollection>
              <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:18477</ns1:id>
              <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
              <ns1:title>Dubstep</ns1:title>
              <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
              <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
              <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
              <ns1:albumArtURI>http://static.beat.no/covers/7d/static/img/sleeveart/00/044/241/0004424171_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
           </ns1:mediaCollection>
        </ns1:getMetadataResult>
     </ns1:getMetadataResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: By empty on Sonos what do you mean?  Is the response blank?  Do you get an Unable to Browse or No Selections Available error on Sonos?

Things to check include does the count and total match the actual numbers returned in the response (hard to tell in the example response you gave) and are any items missing required fields like title or id?

Comment: My Playlists collection screen shows Unable to Browse (Kunne ikke bla gjennom musikk) error. Yes, the count and total match the actual numbers in the response. Yes, all items seem to have title and id.

Comment: Can you please provide the compete getMetadata response? I want to try it locally and see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Please see EDIT 1 above

Comment: Thanks I will try to reproduce and get back to you.

Comment: I have tried reproducing by returning the exact result you have here and everything is working correctly.  I returned your 2 node playlist browse result for the id root and the the content you have here for the id FAVOURITE_PLAYLISTS

This narrows down the issues as the XML is fine so it must be something about how you are returning the XML.  

Can you show me what the HTTP headers are on the response you provided? It is possible that something is wrong there.